# Passing data from a text file to python request only passes the last line

Tags: python, text, python-requests

I am trying to pass as single column text file data to a python request.

Specifically I tried to replace the original data request that looked like this

```
data ='{person:123456}'
```

with the open file below.
The text file structure looks like this:

```
{person:15590665}
{person:15590666}
{person:15590667}
{person:15590668}
```

The problem is that no matter what I do , it only reads the last one (`{person:15590668}`) ignoring all previous ones, the response is correct for this particular one.

This is the request:

```
import requests
import json
cookies = {
    'cookieconsent_status': 'deny',
    'AWSALB': '**************************************************/Q==',
    'AWSALBCORS': '*********************************************==',
    'ctfloginPha': '******************************************************n',
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    # 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'Authorization': '**************************==',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Origin': 'https://**************',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://********************',
    # Requests sorts cookies= alphabetically
    # 'Cookie': 'cookieconsent_status=deny; AWSALB=***********************************************',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    # Requests doesn't support trailers
    # 'TE': 'trailers',
}

with open('person.txt') as fl:
   for line in fl:
      data =line


response = requests.post(
    'https://***************************************',
    cookies=cookies,
    headers=headers,
    data=data,
)
print(response.json())
```

Comment: Your request is posted _after_ `data` is set to the last line of the file as the `for line in fl` loop ends. Why do you expect `data` should contain anything but the last line when you're running the `response = requests.post(...)` line after the loop? Move it to inside the loop. Also print inside the loop

Comment: Since i am a beginner can you please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move your code inside the for loop otherwise you send the request after the loop has finished and data contains the last line.

```py
import requests
import json
cookies = {
    'cookieconsent_status': 'deny',
    'AWSALB': '**************************************************/Q==',
    'AWSALBCORS': '*********************************************==',
    'ctfloginPha': '******************************************************n',
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    # 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'Authorization': '**************************==',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Origin': 'https://**************',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://********************',
    # Requests sorts cookies= alphabetically
    # 'Cookie': 'cookieconsent_status=deny; AWSALB=***********************************************',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    # Requests doesn't support trailers
    # 'TE': 'trailers',
}

with open('person.txt') as fl:
   for line in fl:
        response = requests.post(
            'https://***************************************',
            cookies=cookies,
            headers=headers,
            data=line,
        )
        print(response.json())
```

Comment: I did but with no change, it still sends only the last line.

Comment: I'm pretty confident that the loop works and the post method is called multiple times. At this point are you sure that the rest is correct? Are you sure the file contains many records? Are you sure the credentials are correct? Or are you sure that it is not an API problem on your server?

Comment: Thank you for your input there where two different problems but since you solved the main one, everything is fine now. Cant thank you enough.